# Column [X] does not belong to table server error - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been using this same one line code to save a specific field from my database to a variable.

```
variable = Convert.ToType(dt.Rows[0]["[Column Name]"]);
```

Problem is i'm getting this annoying column doesn't exist server error. This is happening for different tables and different fields with sql queries as simple as "Select * From Table".
I've checked countless of times that the column name is correct , i tried with space in the column name and without - nothing seems to help.

Any idea what's causing this and how to solve it?
Here is the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Column '[Long MSDS Update]' does not belong to table Table.]
System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) +5253191
System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName) +13
SiteMaster.msds_update() in
c:\Users\nravid\Desktop\School\Project\PhillipsSite\Site.master.cs:198
SiteMaster.master_Page_PreLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\nravid\Desktop\School\Project\PhillipsSite\Site.master.cs:92
System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreLoad(EventArgs e) +121
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +699
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the specified column name correctly spelled? You should also double-check your query is retrieving from the right table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were getting this error because you included the brackets [ ]. Remove the square brackets and it should work

Use

```
dt.Rows[0]["Column Name"]
```

Instead of

```
dt.Rows[0]["[Column Name]"]
```

In your case

```
dt.Rows[0]["Long MSDS Update"]
```

Comment: Damn! Damn damn damn damn DAMN. :) :) +1

Comment: Waking up in the morning seeing your question on stackoverflow was answered ... feels like Christmas morning :-)

Answer (score 1):

Run the code below and make sure the output is expected.

```
Debug.WriteLine(dt.TableName);
foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("\t" + column.ColumnName);
}
```

Comment: The Output window in Visual Studio (View -> Output or Ctrl+W,O).

Comment: Then yeah , it printed out the columns names exactly as in the database and exactly the same as the ones in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a test round it

```
if (dt.Columns.Contains("SomeColumnName"))
{
}
else
{
    // Danger Will Robinson!. Danger!
}
```